# Is there a way to find all the locations of implicit type conversions in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way to find all the locations of implicit type conversions in a workspace of Eclipse with tens of thousands of lines of Android Java code?

For example, I want to find all the location where bytes are converted to integers implicitly.

I was thinking about using Preferences > Java > Error/Warnings to generate errors or warning for implicit type conversions, but could not figure out.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you need to do that? If you have ClassCastException (due to implicit casts of generics), use the stack trace to locate the relevant line of code. If you have performance problems, profile your application.

Comment: A specific problem that I am having now is that I suspect some implicit conversions of byte (-128 to 127) to integer are causing a problem in a fairly complicated package. I know the intention is to convert a byte to an integer of 0 to 255 in some cases. I want to examine all the conversions.

Comment: In NetBeans, this setting is called "Auto-boxing/Auto-unboxing" under the Errors and Warnings section, I'd look for something similarly named.

Comment: @MrLore, I have just tried it.  The impression that I got is that configuration is related to conversion between primitives and their corresponding classes such as int and Int, byte and Byte, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, I want to find all the location where bytes are converted to integers implicitly.

AFAIK, no.

> I want to find all the location where bytes are converted to integers implicitly.

I think I would start by looking carefully at all places where you use variables which have type `byte` or a `byte` array type.  And then look at all places where you call a method that returns `byte`.